# How to do multiple `is not` filter effectively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Here's my code

```
df = df[df['scorecard_version'] != '9.0']
df = df[df['scorecard_version'] != '8.0']
df = df[df['scorecard_version'] != '10.0']
df = df[df['scorecard_version'] != '11.0']
df = df[df['scorecard_version'] != '11.1']
```

Is there any shorter alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted boolean mask by `~`:

```
df[~df['scorecard_version'].isin(['9.0','8.0','10.0','11.0','11.1'])]
```

Alternative solution with [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
df[~np.in1d(df['scorecard_version'].values, ['9.0','8.0','10.0','11.0','11.1'])]
```

Comment: Note `np.in1d` is used by `pd.Series.isin` for sufficiently large arrays ([source](http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.1/pandas/core/series.py#L3532-L3590)). So there may be benefits to leaving the decision-making to `pd.Series.isin`.